Can't use record screen on ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I use keyword shortcut from setting(Shift+Ctrl+Alt+R) but it doesn't work. How to solve this problem.
Thank you


Try pressing just printscreen key

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review
